# How to plot a graph of selected rows to from a DT data table in a shiny app

Tags: r, shiny, plotly, dt

In a shiny app I would like to plot a graph from selected rows of a DT data table.

There are two problems I am struggling with:

1. I would prefer the graph to be blank until row selection(s) is/are made and the Graph rows `actionButton` is clicked. Possibly with an empty box as a placeholder for the graph.
2. If I select additional rows after the first selection, additional rows are highlighted in DT but after clicking the Graph rows botton the graph goes blank

Searching SO has revealed similar questions, but I have been unable to relate the answers
I found to these problems. Any guidance or suggestions would be most helpful.

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)

df1 <- data.frame(x = 1:10, y = letters[1:10])

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Select rows from DT to graph"),
    mainPanel(
      fluidRow(dataTableOutput("dt1", height = "40%"),
               actionButton("graphRows", "Graph Rows"),
               plotlyOutput("plot1")
             )
      )
  )


server <- function(input, output) {

  
  values <- reactiveValues(df_4gg = df1)


  observeEvent(input$graphRows,{
    
   if (!is.null(input$dt1_rows_selected)) {

      values$df_4gg <- values$df_4gg[input$dt1_rows_selected, ]
    }
  })


  output$dt1 <- renderDT(
      df1
    )
  
    
  output$plot1 <- renderPlotly({

      p1 <- 
        ggplot(data = values$df_4gg, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
        geom_point() 

    ggplotly(p1)
    
  })


}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Shiny view after first selection of rows and click `Graph rows`
[image]

Shiny view after selection of additional rows and click `Graph rows`

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option to fix your first issue would be to init `df_4gg` with `NULL` and use an `if-else` to display an empty plot in that case. Concerning the second issue, using `values$df_4gg[input$dt1_rows_selected, ]` you are selecting rows from the already "filtered" dataset. Instead I think you want `values$df_4gg <- df1[input$dt1_rows_selected, ]` to select rows from the original dataset:

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)

df1 <- data.frame(x = 1:10, y = letters[1:10])

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Select rows from DT to graph"),
  mainPanel(
    fluidRow(
      dataTableOutput("dt1", height = "40%"),
      actionButton("graphRows", "Graph Rows"),
      plotlyOutput("plot1")
    )
  )
)


server <- function(input, output) {
  values <- reactiveValues(df_4gg = NULL)

  observeEvent(input$graphRows, {
    if (!is.null(input$dt1_rows_selected)) {
      values$df_4gg <- df1[input$dt1_rows_selected, ]
    } else {
      values$df_4gg <- NULL
    }
  })

  output$dt1 <- renderDT(
    df1
  )

  output$plot1 <- renderPlotly({
    p1 <- if (is.null(values$df_4gg)) {
      ggplot()
    } else {
      ggplot(data = values$df_4gg, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
        geom_point()
    }

    ggplotly(p1)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]